# Properly configure load button in tkinter and properly display values from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to coding. Probably 3 weeks coding at most. I need some help properly configuring my load button. In my program I have an entry box and button that auto generates entry boxes with which you then input the values for the dictionary. What I want my load button to do is create the proper amount of entry boxes and populate the text in the entry boxes for you. As of right now, all it does is populate the dictionary in the Label which is kind of useless.

Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from math import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import json
import os

class App:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.entry = Entry(self.root)
        self.button = Button(self.root, text="Input number of items in bag", command=self.command)
        self.done = Button(self.root, text="Save File", command=self.save)
        self.load = Button(self.root, text="Load File", command=self.load_data)
        self.save = Button(self.root, text="Save List", command=self.dict)
        self.frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.browsebutton = Button(root, text="Browse", command=self.browsefunc)
        self.entry.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.button.pack(side=RIGHT) 
        self.save.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.done.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.load.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.browsebutton.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.frame.pack()

        global pathlabel
        pathlabel= Label(self.root)
        pathlabel.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        Label(self.root, text="Enter calculation below:").pack()
        global entry
        entry = Entry(self.root)
        entry.bind("<Return>", self.evaluate)
        entry.pack()
        global res
        res = Label(self.root)
        res.pack()

        global lbl
        lbl = Label(self.root)
        lbl.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        global DND_label
        Label(self.root)
        DND_label = Label(self.root)
        DND_label.pack(side=TOP)


    def command(self):
        self.frame.destroy()
        self.frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.text = []

        for i in range(int(self.entry.get())):
            self.text.append(Entry(self.frame, text="Item " + str(i+1) + ': '))
            self.text[i].pack()
            self.frame.pack()
        lbl.config(text="Enter amount and item name.")


    def dict(self):
        global DND
        DND = {}
        for i in range(len(self.text)):
            DND.update({self.text[i].cget("text"): self.text[i].get()})
        for k, v in DND.items():
            print(v)
        DND_label.configure(text = "Inventory: " + str(DND.values()))

    def save(self):
        DND = {}
        for i in range(len(self.text)):
            DND.update({self.text[i].cget("text"): self.text[i].get()})
        try:
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                newpath = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + "_NEW.txt"
                with open(newpath, 'w') as j:
                    json.dump(DND,j)
                    DND_label.configure(text = "Inventory: " + str(DND.values()))
            for k, v in DND.items():
                print(v)

        except FileNotFoundError:
            try:
                New_dir = os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Documents', 'DND_player_inventories'))
                filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Documents', 'DND_player_inventories')
                file = 'DND_inventory.txt'
                newpath = os.path.join(filepath, file)
                with open(newpath, 'w') as j:
                    json.dump(DND,j)
                    DND_label.configure(text = "Inventory: " + str(DND.values()))
                for k, v in DND.items():
                    print(v)

            except FileExistsError:
                try:
                    filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Documents', 'DND_player_inventories')
                    file = 'DND_inventory.txt'
                    newpath = os.path.join(filepath, file)
                    with open(newpath, 'x') as j:
                        json.dump(DND,j)
                        DND_label.configure(text = "Inventory: " + str(DND.values()))
                    for k, v in DND.items():
                        print(v)

                except FileExistsError:
                    filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Documents', 'DND_player_inventories')
                    file = 'DND_inventory.txt'
                    file = os.path.join(filepath, file)
                    with open(file, 'r') as f:
                        newpath = os.path.join(filepath, file[0:-4]) + "_NEW.txt"
                        with open(newpath, 'w') as j:
                            json.dump(DND,j)
                            DND_label.configure(text = "Inventory: " + str(DND.values()))
                        for k, v in DND.items():
                            print(v)

        except NameError:
            try:
                New_dir = os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Documents', 'DND_player_inventories'))
                filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Documents', 'DND_player_inventories')
                file = 'DND_inventory.txt'
                newpath = os.path.join(filepath, file)
                with open(newpath, 'w') as j:
                    json.dump(DND,j)
                    DND_label.configure(text = "Inventory: " + str(DND.values()))
                for k, v in DND.items():
                    print(v)

            except FileExistsError:
                try:
                    filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Documents', 'DND_player_inventories')
                    file = 'DND_inventory.txt'
                    newpath = os.path.join(filepath, file)
                    with open(newpath, 'x') as j:
                        json.dump(DND,j)
                        DND_label.configure(text = "Inventory: " + str(DND.values()))
                    for k, v in DND.items():
                        print(v)

                except FileExistsError:
                    filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Documents', 'DND_player_inventories')
                    file = 'DND_inventory.txt'
                    file = os.path.join(filepath, file)
                    with open(file, 'r') as f:
                        newpath = os.path.join(filepath, file[0:-4]) + "_NEW.txt"
                        with open(newpath, 'w') as j:
                            json.dump(DND,j)
                            DND_label.configure(text = "Inventory: " + str(DND.values()))
                    for k, v in DND.items():
                        print(v)

    def load_data(self):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            try:
                DND = json.load(f)
            except ValueError:
                DND = {}
            for k, v in DND.items():
                DND_label.configure(text = "Inventory: " + str(DND.values()))
                print(v)

    @staticmethod
    def browsefunc():
        global filename
        filename = askopenfilename()
        pathlabel.config(text=filename)

    @staticmethod
    def evaluate(self):
        res.configure(text = "Answer: " + str(eval(entry.get())))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    global root
    root = Tk()
    root.title('DND Player inventories')
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is what I have for the load button.

```
    def load_data(self):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            try:
                DND = json.load(f)
            except ValueError:
                DND = {}
            for k, v in DND.items():
                DND_label.configure(text = "Inventory: " + str(DND.values()))
                print(v)
```

The other thing I need help with is displaying the dictionary values without the extra wording in there. I use this code below which shows what is in the dictionary, it just doesn't look good.

```
DND_label.configure(text = "Inventory: " + str(DND.values()))
```

Example dictionary, save it in a text file and browse to it to load it. Name of text file doesn't matter.

```
{"Item 1: ": "test", "Item 2: ": "test 1", "Item 3: ": "test 3", "Item 4: ": "test 4"}
```

I am using tkinter for the gui. This is just a project to help me learn. In depth answers to how and why would be very much appreciated. I'm sure there is easier ways to code it but this is understandable to me as I'm learning.

Comment: What we need is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without it we will be guessing at some or most of what you are trying to accomplish. That said what have you tried? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Mike-SMT The code works, just not how I want it to. I'm not really sure where to start or end honestly. I can post the code here if needed. its only about 100 lines. What I want it to do is load the data from the file which is a text file with the dictionary in it and create the entry boxes with the values populated in the entry boxes already. The command function populates the entry boxes by entering a number and generates the dictionary and keys

Comment: I understand what you want to do. My comment is to help you formulate your question to be consistent with what we expect on stack overflow. The link I provided will tell you everything you need to know about providing a MCVE for us to test and elaborate on. For example you do not show your imports and you do not have an example of this dictionary you want to load. We have no clue what kind of data or how your dictionary is formatted. This is important information when providing a response. We need to copy your code then paste it to our IDE and be able to run it. Or at lest see the exact error.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Okay, I'll edit my question to include what's needed. I wasn't sure what to post

Comment: Lots of newcomers are note sure what to post exactly. This is why I and others provide the link to the MCVE post.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I just posted the whole code. Its not too much I don't think and people can see how it operates. Probably easier ways to code it and simpler ways, but I'm learning from this website so it is what it is haha

Comment: Well that is not a MCVE. One reason we ask for an MCVE is that there is a good chance by providing the MCVE you find the problem yourself and if not there is a simple foundation for us to work with.

Comment: Hydro. Can you please provide an example dictionary for loading. This way I can see what we need to do for loading the data.

Comment: @Mike-SMT added the dictionary of what is normally generated. The problem is I have no idea where to start on how to come about to code it correctly. I guess its not really a problem I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring all the other issues I can see with your code, here is a simple MCVE example of how to load a dictionary from a file into your program with values being placed in the entry field.

Please use my below example when formulating future questions as the below example shows a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The bare minimum to reproduce an issue or behavior related to your question. As you can see I do not include things like the title or various other functions or variables that are unrelated to the specific questions.

My example will use a couple class attributes to hold the dictionary and to hold a list used for creating the different fields.

I use a list in this way because I can get the index information easy and use that to programmatically produce the correct labels and entry fields in the correct rows and columns.

By producing this list we can also use it to store new values and save them to a file but that is an answer for another question if you are unable to work it out.

Here is my example dictionary:

```
{"Age":"30", "Name":"Mike", "Job":"Network Engineer"}
```

Here is my code:
Keep in mind you will need to use your own file path to your dictionary file.

```
import tkinter as tk
import json


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.button_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.button_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.data_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.data_frame.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.loaded_dict = {}
        self.data_list = []

        tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Load dictionary data",
                  command=self.load_dict).grid(row=0, column=0)

    def load_dict(self):
        self.loaded_dict = {}
        with open(".path/to/dict_file.txt", "r") as f:
            self.loaded_dict = json.load(f)
        if self.loaded_dict != {}:
            for key, value in self.loaded_dict.items():
                self.data_list.append([tk.Label(self.data_frame, text=key), tk.Entry(self.data_frame), value])
            for ndex, item in enumerate(self.data_list):
                item[0].grid(row=ndex, column=0)
                item[1].grid(row=ndex, column=1)
                item[1].insert(0, item[2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = App()
    root.mainloop()
```

Results:

Before pressing the button:

[image]

After:

[image]

Now this example is very basic and one can do a lot more to manage formatting and resetting of the frame to load something else however this example is the very basic way of loading the dictionary in the manor you requested.

Update:

To answer you question in the comments below we can load just the value to the label by changing what we are doing the `for` loop. In the for loop we are checking the key and the key value of each key/value pair in the dictionary and then doing something with that info. All we need to do is tell the text of your label to be the `value` portion of that pair.

Change this:

```
for key, value in self.loaded_dict.items():
                    self.data_list.append([tk.Label(self.data_frame, text=key), tk.Entry(self.data_frame), value])
                for ndex, item in enumerate(self.data_list):
                    item[0].grid(row=ndex, column=0)
                    item[1].grid(row=ndex, column=1)
                    item[1].insert(0, item[2])
```

To this:

```
for key, value in self.loaded_dict.items():
                self.data_list.append([tk.Label(self.data_frame, text=value), tk.Entry(self.data_frame), value])
            for ndex, item in enumerate(self.data_list):
                item[0].grid(row=ndex, column=0)
                item[1].grid(row=ndex, column=1)
```

Results:

[image]

As stated before this is just a simple example. You can worry about things like formatting later after you get the basics working.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I'll use it and see what I can do with it

Comment: also, do you know how to populate just the values from the dictionary into a label?

Comment: Yes. That is just a matter of loading the correct data from the dictionary to the text field of the label. So using my example do you want the labels to say "Age 30" or just "30"?

Comment: If I wanted it to say just 30, how would I code that?

Comment: @hydro_boy I added an update to my answer to provide the example on your question in the comments.

Comment: Thank you a ton, I appreciate it! Gives me a good place to start on where I need to go and what I need to learn. I appreciate your time